# What encoding to use for the special name in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, encoding

i have this name: éššede+á
I have in mysql but i need search great encoding for this (ASCII, latin1) ?

Because i search where this id from php and not working, problem is characters: (éšš+á) from id: éššede+á

Thanks

Comment: utf8 general ci?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should switch to uft8mb4

But latin1 with a correct collation does also the trick

Basically you need also the correct connection string with the same settings of your table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE name(name1 varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE name_1(name1 varchar(10)) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_danish_ci;
> ```

> ```
> SHOW CREATE TABLE name
> ```
>
> ```
> Table | Create Table                                                                                                                     
> :---- | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> name  | CREATE TABLE `name` (<br>  `name1` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL<br>) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO name VALUES ('éššede+á')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM name WHERE name1 LIKE 'éššede+á'
> ```
>
> ```
> | name1        |
> | :----------- |
> | éššede+á |
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO name_1 VALUES ('éššede+á')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM name_1 WHERE name1 LIKE 'éššede+á'
> ```
>
> ```
> | name1        |
> | :----------- |
> | éššede+á |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d9b313e1a9411f6f06d234147980bf22)*

Comment: No.  While you can stuff any bytes you like into a `latin1` column, you are asking for trouble when you compare or convert or extract the text.  Those 4 accented characters work with latin1, but many others do not work.

Comment: He asked for latin1 to save them and i point in the first sentece he should swutch to utf8mb4, so my answer s is correct

Answer (score 1):

Lots of `CHARACTER SETs` can handle those characters:

```
                         CHARACTER SET        Hex
                    binary, utf8mb4, utf8  C3A9C5A1C5A1C3A1
                           cp1250, latin1  E99A9AE1
                                    cp852  82E7E7A0
                            eucjpms, ujis  8FABB18FABDE8FABDE8FABA1
                                  gb18030  A8A68130943881309438A8A2
                                      hp8  C5ECECC4
                                  keybcs2  82A8A8A0
                                   latin2  E9B9B9E1
                                    macce  8EE4E487
```

latin7 almost works, but not for `á`.

`uft8mb4` is strongly recommended; it handles "everything".